# Weird ImportError when using Python urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I've done this a million times, but for some reason I am getting some weird errors when trying to use urllib2. I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04.

Code:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
urlopen('http://www.google.com').read()
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    urlopen('http://www.google.com').read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1207, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1146, in do_open
    h = http_class(host, timeout=req.timeout) # will parse host:port
  File "/home/nate/httplib.py", line 362, in __init__
ImportError: No module named appengine.api
```

I get a similar error when using urllib. Any idea on what could cause this and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

It appears like you have an httplib.py that is overriding the standard module httplib. And it is trying to import Google App Engine related libraries which doesn't exist. You need to rename the httplib.py to something else.

Answer (score 1):

> File "/home/nate/httplib.py", line 362,

You have a file in your `sys.path` called `httplib.py` which is trying to import appengine.api.

Rename your `/home/nate/httplib.py` something else because it is shadowing the standard library module of the same name.

Comment: It's not in PYTHONPATH. It's in current directory which is the first in sys.path.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you take a look at the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html). It makes working with HTTP a breeze.

"Python’s standard urllib2 module provides most of the HTTP capabilities you need, but the API is thoroughly broken. It was built for a different time — and a different web. It requires an enormous amount of work (even method overrides) to perform the simplest of tasks."

Comment: I will definitely look into this. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: While this is a great suggestion it doesn't answer the question at all. Should be a comment imo.